# How to sort the Scheduled Day with the time in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I sort the days and time in the sql?

Data:

[image]

What I want is:

```
 - Day        |      Time

 - M-W-F      | 08:00 - 09:00 am 
 - M-W-F      | 09:00 - 10:00 am
 - .....................

 - T-Th       | 07:00 - 8:30 am
 - T-Th       | 8:30 - 10:00 am 
 - ....................

 - Sat        | 09:00 - 12:00 am
 - Sat        | 02:00 - 5:00 pm
```

SQL which I have used now:

```
SELECT * FROM subject_scheduled ORDER BY time_day ASC
```

Comment: show your query & table structure..

Comment: What format is this? Is the data stored in the same format in your table? What is the datatype?

Comment: @YusufHassan My datatype was only a text, and it is also stored in one table.

Comment: is this stored in 1 column ? can you please give us the DDL(or mention columns in your query) for your source table?

Comment: Where would M-T-Sat appear in this result? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, store start and end times separately

Comment: Also note that saturday's class ends at midnight

Answer (score 0):

Try below query . If you know what day you are going to store in day column then you can define sequence in a temp table and use that for sorting.

```
Declare  @MasterData table (day varchar(111),seq int)
insert into @MasterData
select 'M-W-F',1
union
select 'T-Th' , 2
union
select 'Sat',3

select t.* 
From subject_scheduled t 
join @MasterData m on t.Day=m.day
order by m.seq,left(time,2) asc
```

You might need to dig deep on time as i am not sure how you are storing like if its start from AM and end PM what you are going to store.

Comment: This is very tricky sir. I actually have the column full_sched in which the day and the time are collided (such as "M-W-F 07:00 - 08:00 am, T-Th 08:30 - 10:00 pm").